# Where to save data in express.js app other than database?

Tags: node.js, express

I am showing a link on a page and I want to change that link, by using a form.

**where should I save that link and retrieve to render the page other that a database?**

*I think involving database for such a small task is not performance efficient.

---

what I can do is save it in a global variable as a string, so that I can access it and change it.

But is it a good practice to use global variable for such task in production?

Comment: my opinion its bad practice, you will then need to amend the file on a form submit, to change the variable so that each time its refreshed its picking up the amend to the file. You need a db if you ask me.

Comment: To help you, we need to understand more.  Are you trying to change a link for one particular user, just in their page or are you trying to change all instances of that link for all users who use your web server?  Then, under what condition are you trying to change the link and how long do you want it to last?  Is this something, you can just change once with client-side Javascript or does it need to affect all future pages rendered from the server for that user?

Comment: @jfriend00 Answers to all your questions=> Are you trying to change all instances of that link for all users who use your web server? : YES. | Under what condition are you trying to change the link and how long do you want it to last? : I want to change it using a form which will be only available in admin user login (I have already implemented user management using passport so this is not a issue) and it will not be changed frequently (may be every 7 days). |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now that we know that this is a change that you want to affect all users, then a global or preferably a module-level variable or a property on a module-shared object would be fine.

If you want this change to be persistent and survive a server restart, then you would need to write the change to disk somewhere and have code that reads that setting back in from disk when your server restarts.  A simple way to do that might be to read/write it to a file in the JSON format.  That gives you simple extensibility to also include other settings in that file.

Your admin form can then just update this variable and trigger a save to disk of all the current settings.

Answer (score 1):

I believe which approach you want to implement really depends on the scenario e.g. how frequently will the link be changed, how frequently will it be read etc. A couple of suggestions:

1. If different user wants to see and update the same link without affecting others, you can use on client side stored cookies. Then you won't need a db but each user will manage their own link that no one else can access.
2. You could use a file e.g. json or simple text file and use built in `fs` to read and write into that file. However in that case you would want to use sync operations to avoid concurrency issues e.g. `const contents = fs.readFileSync('storage.txt', 'utf8');`
3. Of course you could store data in a string too, however if server was to go down, the link would not persist.

Comment: 1st method you have mentioned is not what I need because that link will be same for all users.
I have not mentioned in my question, but I have already implemented 2nd method mentioned, but when I submit the form with new data it work fine that is file's data changes but, when I redirect( after file operation ) user to a page the page gets stuck(page loads partially) or fails to load but when I refresh manually it works fine after that. So it's very annoying.